# Javascript: An efficient way to verify that a name is composed of a set of characters

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a system where the user needs to enter several names (chosen by them). I want to create a "name verifier". Basically it needs to make sure that all characters in the string entered as a name are either letters (lowercase and uppercase), numbers and a few special characters (like , : . * _ - +).

Now the way I thought about doing this was declaring a huge constant array of all the permited characters and the iterate over the string like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
  if (permitted_chars.indexOf(name[i]) === -1) return false;
}
return true;
```

However since both the array of permited chars and the names can be quite large (not to mention actually writing the array) it seems like a bad idea.

Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, use regular expressions!

Comment: There definitely is another way, take a look at MDN's page on Regular Expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). If you're not familiar with them, I *highly* suggest doing some reading on them. Essentially, they're a very powerful way of searching and validating strings (to name a couple of their primary uses).

```
var string = "Abcd_1234";
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
regex.test(string) //=> true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just so I know I understand. This esentially matches 0 or more instances of the set composed by a through z, A though Z 0 though 9 and the underscore. Right?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

```
var disallowChars = ['*', ',', '-'];
var regex = new RegExp('[\\'+disallowChars.join('\\')+']');
regex.test("test") #=> false
regex.test("test*") #=> true

var string = "string to be, validated"
if(regex.test(string))
    alert('invalid input')
```

Comment: Ok, I have used Regular Expressions before. I was interested in this code. Just to see if I understand correctly. Basically what this does is create a regular expression that matches any NOT wanted characters, right? If it matches it means that the string is no valid. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if the `RegExp` match any disallowed characters in the string it will return true, otherwise false, just like `indexOf`

Comment: @aarelovich That's correct. This is probably not the right solution, however, as the list of disallowed characters will most likely far outnumber the characters you allow - it's preferable to take the opposite approach.